# Removing an element from dictionary of list of dataframes

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop

this is my data structure:

```
'CRWD', [        Date      CRWD
0 2020-10-01  0.040416
1 2020-10-02 -0.020998,         Date      CRWD
0 2020-10-05  0.035819
1 2020-10-06  0.001726
2 2020-10-07 -0.003859
3 2020-10-08 -0.011067
4 2020-10-09  0.004197,         Date      CRWD
0 2020-10-12  0.016647
1 2020-10-13  0.046862
2 2020-10-14 -0.032788
3 2020-10-15 -0.016442
4 2020-10-16 -0.000138]
```

So its {StockTicker : [week1,week2,week3,etc]} where weekX corresponds to a dataframe of each day within that week.
I want to remove the days that are not a full week (like week1 in this example). Here's how I do it:

```
for k in weekList.keys():
    for x in weekList[k]:
        if len(x) <= 3:
            weekList[k].remove(x) #Where error occurs
weekList
```

I get this error:
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

In the code, x is type dataframe, while weekList[k] is type List. I thought this means I could treat each element within the list as such, but the issue seems to be that the element of the list is a dataframe. This is odd because I just want to remove it from the list. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because if you use `list.remove(x)`, that is actually scanning the entire `list` to find an element equal to `x` and remove it. But to do this Python needs to compare `x` (a DataFrame object) to the elements in the `list` (also DataFrames), and it cannot do so as the `ValueError` is telling you.

Try the following, it should work:

```py
for i, x in enumerate(weekList[k]):
    if len(x) <= 3:
        del weekList[k][i] #Where error occurs
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
print({k: v for k, v in weekList.items() if len(v) > 3})
```

Comment: This checks the length of the list (48 weeks), not the length of entries in each list item. I can add some more data if you'd like